# How to use different ghc builds with stack?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I would like to have different, non-ABI-compatible, builds of the same version of GHC, and use them in different projects.

(In my case, the difference between the builds is integer-simple vs gmp.)

The comments in [this issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/399) show how to add a custom flavor of ghc to `stack-setup-2.yaml`. But how do I specify which ghc build to use in each particular case or project?

I.e. I am looking for one (better yet, both) of:

1. The ability to specify in `stack.yaml` whether to use the integer-simple or gmp build.
2. The ability to specify, at `stack build` time, which build to produce.

Comment: You can use the [`ghc-variant` option](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-variant) or `--ghc-variant` flag. If you are on Windows and use [the default stack-setup-2.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/stackage-content/master/stack/stack-setup-2.yaml), building with `--ghc-variant integersimple` should use a different GHC than if you use `--ghc-variant standard`.

Comment: @sjakobi great, could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the `ghc-variant` option](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-variant) or `--ghc-variant` flag.

If you are on Windows and use the default [stack-setup-2.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/stackage-content/master/stack/stack-setup-2.yaml), building with `--ghc-variant integersimple` should use a different GHC than if you use `--ghc-variant standard`.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are good, but here's a complete example so that you don't have to puzzle it together from the provided links.

Put this in your `stack.yaml` file:

```
resolver: lts-12.20

setup-info:
  ghc:
    linux64-custom-dwarf:
      8.4.4:
        url: "https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.4/ghc-8.4.4-x86_64-deb9-linux-dwarf.tar.xz"
        sha256: f9cac6e402c71d7251f2e22f412fb4abd72c64f34481a1e548cd7f6ff2352a07

ghc-variant: dwarf
```

Here in the `setup-info` part I provide the path to the bindist, a checksum (optional but recommended for reproducibility), and then say that I want to use this custom ghc with `ghc-variant: dwarf` (it seems to turn the `dwarf` in there into `linux64-custom-dwarf` by appending the word to `linux64-custom-`).

If you want to share the definition of that custom ghc across projects, you can also put the `setup-info` part into `$HOME/.stack/config.yaml`.

---

Note for GHC hackers: If you want to hack on ghc itself and iterate quickly on your packages with frequently updated GHC, then [this approach](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/725#issuecomment-364624897) where you just override the GHC binary instead of declaring a fully built bindist is better (because you don't have to build a bindist every time you recompile).

Comment: `macosx-custom-` if you're on mac.

Answer (score 2):

For people who want to try a different ghc version and not an entirely different build alltogether the `--compiler` flag is useful https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#compiler

Also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35472448/1833322 which talks about the `--ghc-variant` flag

And to be complete, here is the talk about the implementation of these flags:

- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/530
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/816

This is useful to know since this stackoverflow question is the first page in google results.

Answer (score 1):

To whoever needs this again, I'll leave a recipe to install **musl bindist** using Stack (GHC 8.6.5 on Alpine) — as another example/variation of what OP has asked.

First, locate a *bindist* (binary distribution) at e.g. https://github.com/commercialhaskell/ghc/releases
I needed to pick the musl libc variant.

Fill that into `setup-info` section in `~/.stack/config.yaml` and specify `ghc-variant`:

```yaml
setup-info:
  ghc:
    linux64-custom-musl-ncurses6:
      8.6.5:
        url: "https://github.com/commercialhaskell/ghc/releases/download/ghc-8.6.5-release/ghc-8.6.5-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.xz"
        content-length: 140167348
        sha1: 3ce575af840e886ba5d2641f68577ace38ac21c6
        sha256: ec6d0417822c3bfafc7aea0b0402294901231bc5d72dd17a2b849e3f44850695

ghc-variant: musl
```

With that, installing the GHC variant is as simple as:

```
stack setup \
    --install-ghc \
    --resolver=$RESOLVER_CHOICE \
    --ghc-variant musl \
    8.6.5
```